# How to use media queries for mobile devices and desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I know that this kind of questions were asked before, I've looked them up but still couldn't quite get my mind around it. Here's my problem:
I want the index page of my website to look in desktop layout on desktops and mobile jquery on mobile devices. I set up my website and its css file only for desktops so far, but when I try to use media queries for mobile devices and create a new css for that I just can't see how I can affiliate that new css with mobile jquery. It seems to me as if I need to create a new source index file for that altogether.

Thanks for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be done through media queries, at least not your question.

### First step

You need only one html file but 2 sets of javascript and css files. One set will cover desktop site and other set will cover jQuery mobile js and css.

### Second step

Next step is to determine if browser is desktop or mobile. It can be done in few ways:

#### Script 1:

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
var check = false;
(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
return check; }
```

Usage:

```
if(mobilecheck()) {
    alert('mobile'); 
} else {
    alert('desktop');
}
```

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qqnZ2/

#### Script 2:

Other solution lean more toward using User Agents. Take a look at the scripts on [DetectMobileBrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

No matter which solution you choose you need to use it for a simple if check, is it desktop or is it mobile.

## Third step:

At this point we need to some kind of resource loader. We will need to to initialize one of ours js/css sets.

Again this can be done in few ways:

#### Solution 1:

Take a look at [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), which is a simply conditional resource loading script. It is also a part of a Modernizer framework. It can be used like this (lets say you picked script 1 from a second step):

```
yepnope({
    test : mobilecheck(),
    yep  : ['jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js', jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css'],
    nope : ['index.js', 'index.css']
});
```

or you can use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). Equally good like yepnope but I find it lacking in case of a large jQuery Mobile files.